# Load data from a property of the result object in Webix

Tags: javascript, ajax, lazy-loading, webix

I have a [Webix list](http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.list.html) and want to [load](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.list_load.html) data dynamically. The problem is that the data is under the `results.entries` key in the JSON object returned by the AJAX call. How should I load that data?

So far what I came up with is slightly convoluted:

```
var result = webix.ajax().sync().get('/my-rest-endpoint');
$$('mylist').parse(JSON.parse(result.responseText).results.entries);
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous!

Answer (score 0):

With **sync()** method, callback is synchronous. But I recomended to you if your **'/my-rest-endpoint'** has a waiting time to be generated, use ajax **async()** method, like this example

```
webix.ajax().get('/my-rest-endpoint',{
    // Error callback
    error:function(text, data, XmlHttpRequest){
        alert("error");
    },

    //Success callback
    success:function(text, data, XmlHttpRequest){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        $$('mylist').parse(data.results.entries);
    }
});
```

Regards